# Xcode Compile Flag to Suppress Nullability Warnings not Working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

For a limited time I want to suppress these kind of warnings the compiler is showing me in Xcode 7.3.1:

`<File>: Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified)`

I have added this compiler flag to all classes under My Target/Build Phases/Compile Sources:
`-Wnullability-completeness`

But it's not working - the warnings are still shown. How can I get rid of the warnings?

Comment: Did you clear out the existing warnings?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To *disable* those warnings, you want: `-Wno-nullability-completeness`. Note the `no-`; the flag you're using *enables* those warnings.

Comment: Cool, that worked on the .m files. Any idea how to disable it for the .h files?

Comment: I added this in XCode 9 (or 8) by adding it to `Build Settings` -> `Apple LLVM 9.0 - Custom compiler flags` -> `Other Warning Flags`. You can just search for `Other Warning Flags`

Comment: In Xcode 10, this was moved to Apple Clang - Custom Compiler Flags > Other Warning Flags

Answer (score 9):

Note that in Xcode 11 it is now `-Wno-nonnull`

It should be set in "Other Warning Flags" in the "Apple Clang - Custom Compiler Flags" section of your target.

You could also avoid these warnings and setting the above altogether by removing these flags Xcode automatically adds to new header files in Objective-C:

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Comment: Sorry under which field to set this flag in Xcode 11?

Comment: @hyouuu I have updated the question to show where it should be set.

Answer (score 8):

Settings for Xcode 11.5 when using project with mixed sources, ObjC and Swift:

```
WARNING_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -Wno-nullability-completeness
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = $(inherited) -Xcc -Wno-nullability-completeness
```

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 11.3, these started appearing out of nowhere in my pure Swift project on the Github ci. That was because I am importing the AWS Objective-C SDK.

Confoundingly, this would only occur on the first build, probably creating the module map for the framework. Hence it was only a problem on ci because of the clean builds.

Fixed it by adding this to the **Swift** compiler options (search for `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` in your build settings):

```
-Xcc -Wno-nullability-completeness
```